# Extending vector grid in QGIS

Tags: qgis, vector-grid

I created vector grids in QGIS of size 2*2km.

Now I have to add few more grids of the same size to these existing grids. Is this possible in QGIS?

Comment: Wouldnt it be easier to recreate the entire grid? Or do you have data stored in the grid which you want to keep?

Comment: I have data stored in the grids, making new grids entirely will create difficulty for my analysis.

Comment: Is your grid in lines or polygons?

Comment: @TeddyTedTed polygons

Comment: Try creating the new grid as a line geometry, then in the processing toolbox use the 'Split with lines' tool use use the new line grid to divide up the original polygon grid.

Answer (score 2):

As an idea you can try using the `"Translate"` geoalgorithm from the QGIS's Toolbox.

*'Offset distance (x-axis)'* and *'Offset distance (y-axis)'* will be a combination of two values from a set of `(len, 0, -len)` values, where `len` is the a length/width of your grid layer.

```
('len', 0)
('len', '-len')
('len', 'len')
(0, 'len')
(0, '-len')
('-len', 'len')
('-len', 0)
('-len', '-len')
```

So, it is like a [Moore neighborhood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore_neighborhood), where there is a central cell and there are eight cells which surround it.

Here is an example:

[image]

---

**References:**

- [Docs » QGIS User Guide » 23.1.15.78. Translate](https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#translate)